# How to Split String With Regular Expression ios objectivec

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

Below is the Syntax of Java : `Code.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");`

I want to convert this in ios objective c

string Code : LR00001 or BLNS-9-M

I want O/p as:

- if code is LR00001 then Array gives me two values. On 0th index it gives LR and in 1 index it gives me 00001
- if code is BLNS-9-M then Array[0] BLNS and Array[1] 9-M

This o/p is working in Java but want in ios objective c.

This regular expression: `(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)` means it finds position in the string where there is a non-digit (`\D`) character before that position and a digit (`\d`) after it.
i.e matches a position between a non-digit (`\D`) and a digit (`\d`).

Following Code I have tried :

1.

```
NSArray *arrComponents = [strCode componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"]];
```

2.

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:strCode options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strStyleCode length])];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:strCode options:0 range: NSMakeRange(0, [strStyleCode length])];
NSLog(@"group1: %@", [strCode substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]]);
NSLog(@"group2: %@", [strCode substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
```

3.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"];
```

All of the above do not work.

I want the same output in ios objective c.

[LR,00001]
[BLNS,9-M]

Comment: What is the logic by which `BLNS-9-M` becomes `BLNS` and `9-M`?

Comment: regular Expression "'(?<=\D)(?=\d)" is the logic by which we have to split the string

Comment: Your Java produces `["BLNS-", "9-M"]` for the second case. You do not say what your Objective-C produces.

Comment: Objective c wont split anything it jus produces the same code which m giving i.e. "BLNS-9-M" @ CRD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first replace all the matches with a non-used symbol, say, with `\x00` null char, and then split with it:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *str = @"LR00001";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)" options:nil error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@"\x00"];
NSArray *chunks = [modifiedString componentsSeparatedByString: @"\x00"];
for(NSString *c in chunks) {
    NSLog(@"%@", c);
}
```

It prints `LR` and `00001`.

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/QQVUM98157).

Answer (score 1):

Java's `String.split` uses a regular expression to match the delimiter, possibly zero-length, at which the string should be split. It then extracts the parts of the string before and after the match, it doesn't extract anything the RE matched.

Objective-C has methods to divide a string, `componentsSeparatedBy...`, but none of these take a regular expression. Your first attempt tries to use one of these by defining a character set using your regular expression – however you cannot define a character set this way and even if you could the set of characters in your particular delimiter is empty.

Your third attempt is incomplete so we'll skip that.

Now your second attempt locates the delimiter using `firstMatchInString:`, but having found it does not try to extract the strings before and after that delimiter, i.e. you don't perform an actual split. If you do that you have the makings of an Objective-C equivalent of Java's split.

In outline:

1. Use `firstMatchInString:` to locate the first delimiter in your string
2. If the match fails you've finished, add the remaining string to your collection of components and return.
3. If the match succeeds then:

   1. extract the substring up to the start of the delimiter match – part of the result of `firstMatchInString:` is an `NSRange`, that contains a starting index, and `NSString` has methods to extract substrings based on indexes.
   2. extract the substring after the delimiter match – similar to the above but remember to allow for the length of the match when calculating the index where this substring starts
   3. you now need to split this second substring, so go back to step 1 and repeat the process using this substring.

You can code the above as a simple `while` loop in Objective-C.

If while trying to implement this algorithm you get stuck ask a new question, show your code, explain your issue, include a link back to this question, and someone will undoubtedly help you.

HTH

Comment: what if i don't have hyphen - in my code?? like is shown second code as LR00001? then in that case whats d scenario? @CRD

Comment: Forgot to mention that in the answer: If you do intend a hyphen to be included as part of the delimiter, which is *not* what your Java code does, you just need to modify your regular expression to allow for an optional hyphen in the delimiter. Doing that means a hyphen will be included in the match range for the delimiter and hence not be part of either component.

Comment: but without modifying my regular expression in java it gives me solution of lr0001 it splits it as d regular expression itself means that it will take the values between nondigits and digits thats what regular expression signifies

Comment: You don't need to modify the RE *unless* you want to treat a hyphen as part of it, otherwise leave your RE as is. What you need to do is implement a version of Java's `split` which is what the above algorithm does.